# Running multiple syncronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to create a situation where 3 people are having a conversation. The situation will be like this.
A is talking while B and C won't do anything.
B is talking while A and C won't do anything.
C is talking while B and A won't do anything.
This means only one thread will remain active at a time. As I am new to this, first
I am trying to print

A

B

C

3 times using 3 synchronized methods. But instead of these it is printing

A

C

B

here is my code:

```java
    public class Chat {
    synchronized void chatA(){
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.println("A");
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            notify();
        }
    }
    synchronized void chatB(){
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.println("B");
            
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            notify();
        }
        
    }
    synchronized void chatC(){
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.println("C");
            notify();
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Chat chat = new Chat();
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                chat.chatA();
            }
        };
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                chat.chatB();   
            }
        };
        t2.start();
        Thread t3 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                chat.chatC();   
            }
        };
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

Please tell me what is I am missing.

Comment: If you're trying to print A,B,C in that order, why are you using multiple threads? Having things happen in the order you specify them is what a single thread does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chat object needs to keep state that remembers which methods have been called already. Like

```
private boolean calledA = false;
```

Then the methods update this state, and use these to decide whether to keep waiting, so that chatC for instance would start with

```
while (!calledB) {
    wait(); 
}
```

Where the waiting thread will be woken up by A or B notifying, then the thread has to check the Boolean to know whether methodB was called.

Also since these 3 threads are using the same monitor and A’s notify could wake up B or C but not both, use notifyAll instead, so you avoid the situation where a thread receives a notification but can’t act on it, while the thread that can act doesn’t receive a notification. If you use notify, the scheduler picks which thread receives the notification, and that may not be the thread you want.

Comment: I am trying to keep active only one thread at a time. So notifyAll will activate all.

Comment: @armanruhit: not really, it wakes up both threads but only one will be able to act based on the variables I am advising you to add.

Comment: thank you so much. It is working now